# File management with BufferedInput/OutputStream

Tags: java, file

I'm using BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream to copy a mp4 video programatically. It's being correctly copied, EXCEPT because I lose the audio! This is my code:

```
    FileInputStream fi = null;
    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    try {
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Zerok\\Videos\\v.mp4");
        fi = new FileInputStream(f);
        fo = new FileOutputStream("video.mp4");
        BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(fi);
        BufferedOutputStream buffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fo);

        int read;
        while((read = buffIn.read()) != -1){
            buffOut.write(read);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication13.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication13.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fi.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication13.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

The video.mp4 file works properly just except of the audio lack. What's causing this? I'm using these classes correctly?

Comment: You are not closing your buffOut/fo. Is that on purpose? That is the only thing I can say. What exactly does it mean that you lose the audio?

Comment: You just won the prize! That was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I wasn't closing my BufferedOutputStream. I used this try-with-resources block, which automatically closes the resource once it's finished:

```
 try (BufferedOutputStream buffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fo)) {
                int read;
                System.out.println("Beginning to copy...");
                while((read = buffIn.read()) != -1){
                    buffOut.write(read);
                }
            }
```

Now the audio reproduces perfectly.